# Array Formula with IF function and SUMIFS function

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I am trying to convert the below formula into an array formula. I can make it work in an array, but it displays the wrong values, compared to the normal formula which I have to drag down.

Normal formula:

```
=if(K4>0,
 (if(((sumifs($K$4:$K,$A$4:$A,A4)-(sumifs($L$4:$L,$A$4:$A,A4))))=0,11,
 (if((sumifs($M$4:$M,$A$4:A,A4))>0,5,)))),12)
```

I tried the below in an array formula, and it skips value 5 and only displays 11 or 12.

Array formula:

```
=arrayformula({"";if(K4:K>0,(if(((sumifs(K4:K,A4:A,A4:A)-
 (sumifs(L4:L,A4:A,A4:A))))=0,11,(if((sumifs(M4:M,A4:A,A4:A))>0,5,)))),12)})
```

I then use a `vlookup` to look against the value, that the if function provides against a list of status messages.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet pls

Comment: Hi user0, link to sheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1amCRzpBieacMdtSftkU0LPcsDDhdelJZVkamWc2dEBE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(K4:K>0, 
 IF(VLOOKUP(A4:A, QUERY({A4:A, K4:K}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1", 0), 2, 0)-
    VLOOKUP(A4:A, QUERY({A4:A, L4:L}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1", 0), 2, 0)=0, 11, 
 IF(VLOOKUP(A4:A, QUERY({A4:A, M4:M}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1", 0), 2, 0)>0, 5)), 12))}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi User0, thats pretty damn sweet! Thank you :) but...For some reason, if I add a letter after 55555 for example, the first line in O will show N/A, but 2nd line will show 12. Is there a way to get round that?

Comment: try: `={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(K4:K>0, 
 IF(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A4:A), QUERY({TO_TEXT(A4:A), K4:K}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1", 0), 2, 0)-
    VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A4:A), QUERY({TO_TEXT(A4:A), L4:L}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1", 0), 2, 0)=0, 11, 
 IF(VLOOKUP(TO_TEXT(A4:A), QUERY({TO_TEXT(A4:A), M4:M}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1", 0), 2, 0)>0, 5)), 12))}` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6u79.png

Comment: Whooooa, works amazingly well!!! Thank you! :))

Comment: Hi User0, I've tried amending this to include another question. Wondered if you could help? If L is >0 show 6. I amended the spreadsheet to help you get an idea what I mean.

Comment: Don't worry, worked it out. :)